# Linq Intermediate Object in method chain for Where and Select?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I am dealing with DocumentFormat.xml.

I need to do work to get to the data I need for the where clause.

But then I need to do the same work in the where clause to construct the desired object.

This seems wasteful.

Is there a better way to construct this?

```
var rowData = registersRows
    .Where(row =>
    {
        var cells = row.Elements<Cell>().ToList();
        return included.Contains(GetCellText(cells, "A", row.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems));
    })
    .Select(row =>
    {
        var cells = row.Elements<Cell>().ToList();
        return new RegistersRow
        {
            StoreNumber = GetCellText(cells, "A", row.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
            ChannelName = GetCellText(cells, "D", row.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
            ChannelDisplayName = GetCellText(cells, "E", row.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
            PhysicalDeviceName = GetCellText(cells, "F", row.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
            FriendlyName = GetCellText(cells, "G", row.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
            DisplayNameInLabel = GetCellText(cells, "H", row.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
            NumberOfRegisters =
                int.Parse(GetCellText(cells, "K", row.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems))
        };
    }).ToList();
```

Specifically in this example I need to extract the StoreNumber and obtain the Cells twice.

Comment: I don't follow "in the where clause"? Did you mean in the "Select" lambda?

Comment: Yeah, from the `WHERE` function to the `SELECT` function, in other words pass the intermediate result of the WHERE function so the SELECT function doesn't have to do the same work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use LINQ with query syntax, you have the `let` keyword that creates a temporary to use later in the query. When the query syntax is translated by the compiler into fluent/lambda syntax, the `let` is translated into a `Select` that bundles the temporary values with any values you need to carry into future methods.

You can do the same manually:

```
var rowData = registersRows
    .Select(r => new { RowIndex = r.RowIndex, cells = r.Elements<Cell>().ToList() })
    .Select(rc => new { rc.RowIndex, rc.cells, A = GetCellText(rc.cells, "A", rc.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems) })
    .Where(rca => included.Contains(rca.A))
    .Select(rca => new RegistersRow {
        StoreNumber = rca.A,
        ChannelName = GetCellText(rca.cells, "D", rca.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
        ChannelDisplayName = GetCellText(rca.cells, "E", rca.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
        PhysicalDeviceName = GetCellText(rca.cells, "F", rca.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
        FriendlyName = GetCellText(rca.cells, "G", rca.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
        DisplayNameInLabel = GetCellText(rca.cells, "H", rca.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems),
        NumberOfRegisters =
                int.Parse(GetCellText(rca.cells, "K", rca.RowIndex, sharedStringTableItems))
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That's a great way to think about it. Thanks!